# Why set --privileged for VPN container?

Tags: docker, containers, vpn

I want to setup a `VPN` with docker container? I find a popular image [mobtitude/vpn-pptp](https://hub.docker.com/r/mobtitude/vpn-pptp/).

This is the start options.

```
# docker run -d --privileged -p 1723:1723 -v {local_path_to_chap_secrets}:/etc/ppp/chap-secrets mobtitude/vpn-pptp
```

I am confused why add the --privileged flat.

Answer (score 0):

Some quotes from Docker official references

> By default, Docker containers are “unprivileged” and cannot, for example, run a Docker daemon inside a Docker container. This is because by default a container is not allowed to access any devices, but a “privileged” container is given access to all devices (see the documentation on cgroups devices).
>
> When the operator executes `docker run --privileged`, Docker will enable to access to all devices on the host as well as set some configuration in AppArmor or SELinux to allow the container nearly all the same access to the host as processes running outside containers on the host. Additional information about running with `--privileged` is available on the [Docker Blog](https://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/).

Comment: I am not familiar withe VPN, but I think VPN don't use any device. The reason seems to related with AppArmor and SELinux. Does VPN use AppArmor/SELinux or both?